# S3 Images Won't Show On Parse Server

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, amazon-s3

I have migrated my app to mongo and heroku. I am now working on making sure all the PFFiles, which are all images, get migrated to my S3. I ran through the tutorial and code, and verified my pictures DO appear in S3 bucket, and that mongoDb updated the names of them. However, when I run the app and try to view a picture I get this:

[Error]: Response status code was unacceptable: 403 (Code: 1, Version: 1.14.2)

Here is my index.js

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
if (!databaseUri) {
console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://MYSTUFF/app',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'APPID',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MASTER',
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://fritchchurch.herokuapp.com/parse', // Don't forget to change to https if needed

filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || "KEYID",
process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || "ACCESSKEY",
process.env.BUCKET_NAME || "fritchdirectory",
{directAccess: true}

),

liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Users", "FritchDirectory"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
}

});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you should set your file key in your initialization of the parse server. It won't access without that:

```
fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || 'file_key',
```

Also, make sure your policy is set up correctly for the AWS IAM user you are using in your new S3Adapter code bit. Here's what I followed: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters

Hopefully that will cover it although there are other things it can be.

I'm having a weird version of this problem where I can upload images but can't pull them down. I get this whenever I try to pull them down:

```
2017-01-04 19:38:51.417576 Nomnomz[2711:2280806] [Error]: Response status code was unacceptable: 403 (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)
```

It's probably some association issue where it want's to pull photos from Parse.com although I'm uploading them to the S3 bucket. No clue why. Let me know if you have ideas on it.